# Adding pdf page number/amount back when using powerline with docview

Tags: docview, powerline

So I started using the powerline addon for emacs, and I noticed that among other things, by default it hides the page number of the pdf file (for instance P1/4) in the mode line. Is there any way to configure powerline to put that feature back? I like being able to see how long the pdf document is (not to mention, it doubles as a download counter when viewing pdfs through eww).

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own powerline theme.
Just look into <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> [`powerline-themes.el`](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/blob/6ef4a06c3c583045accbc957b6f449b7c0c57cd8/powerline-themes.el#L44-L99) <kbd>RET</kbd>, copy the theme function of your joice to your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) and insert
`(powerline-raw mode-line-position face0 'l)`
at an appropriate place.

Note, that you should always `(require 'powerline)` before setting a theme. Otherwise you cannot revert the powerline to the normal emacs version.

Maybe, it is wise to add `(require 'powerline)` behind the [`(interactive)` form](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/blob/6ef4a06c3c583045accbc957b6f449b7c0c57cd8/powerline-themes.el#L46) of your customized theme function.

If you do not like to define a whole powerline theme you can also add `mode-line-position` to an existing theme with the following Elisp snippet.

It is demonstrated with `powerline-default-theme`, but you can apply it to other themes with small obvious modifications.

```el
(require 'powerline)

(defun find-branch (node tree)
  "Find the cons with car NODE in TREE."
  (catch 'found
    (cl-nsublis (list (list node)) tree
        :test (lambda (ref item)
            (when (and
                   (listp item)
                   (equal ref (car item)))
              (throw 'found item))))
    nil))
;; Test:
;; (find-branch 'lhs mode-line-format)
;; (find-branch 'gotcha '(first (second gotcha third)))

(defun add-car (list car &rest cars)
  "Add CAR as first element of LIST by modifying it.
May also be applied to an argument list of CARS."
  (if cars
      (dolist (next-car (nreverse (cons car cars)))
        (add-car list next-car))
    (setcdr list (cons (car list) (cdr list)))
    (setcar list car))
  list)
;; (let ((l (list -1 1 2 3))) (add-car (cdr l) 0) l)
;; (let ((l (list -1 1 2 3))) (add-car (cdr l) -0.5 0 0.5) l)

(defun my-powerline-add-position ()
  "Add mode-line-position to powerline."
  (let ((branch (cdadr (find-branch 'lhs mode-line-format))))
    (unless (find-branch 'mode-line-position branch)
      (add-car (cl-member 'powerline-buffer-id branch :key 'car)
           '(powerline-raw mode-line-position face0 'r)))))

(advice-add 'powerline-default-theme :after #'my-powerline-add-position)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing today when testing [telephone-line](https://github.com/dbordak/telephone-line), [spaceline](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline) or [simple-modeline](https://github.com/gexplorer/simple-modeline)

The one that worked out-of-the-box was [doom-modeline](https://github.com/seagle0128/doom-modeline) (See screenshot below).
[image]

From the [installation instructions](https://github.com/seagle0128/doom-modeline?tab=readme-ov-file#install) it is only necessary to add the following lines to the `init.el` file:

```
(require 'doom-modeline)
(doom-modeline-mode 1)
```

In my case I use `straight.el` so the following is the code I use. No extra configuration is needed to show the page number.

```
(use-package doom-modeline
  :straight (doom-modeline :type git 
           :flavor melpa 
           :host github 
           :repo "seagle0128/doom-modeline")
  :init (doom-modeline-mode 1)
)
```